# Is there any way to implement find_in_batches 'finish' option in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

`find_in_batches` in Rails 3.2 doesn't support finish/end/end_at option

Need any work around. Thanks

Comment: did you try find_each

Comment: Yes, but I need batches to proceed further. I can't proceed with each record nor with all.

Comment: find_each can work in batches https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each

Comment: "find_each method is only intended to use for batch processing of large amounts of records that wouldn’t fit in memory all at once. If you just need to loop over less than 1000 records, it’s probably better just to use the regular find methods"

Comment: User.find_each { |user| user.some_method }

By default, the above will only load 1,000 User objects into memory, and your server will thank you. If 1,000 is too big/small for you, use the :batch_size option to change it. The find_in_batches method is similar except that it provides the array to the block instead of one object at a time. For example:

User.find_in_batches do |users|
  users.each { |user| user.some_method }
end

Comment: 'find_in_batches provides the array to the block instead of one object at a time' - Exactly, I need to perform block operation on 40 records.